# capture_haml in helper not displaying parameter values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, helper

I'm trying to use a helper in my rails view to draw some haml lines, the fact is that it is writing the html tags, but no content in them.

Here's my helper:

```
def detail_line(model, column, value)
  capture_haml do  
    haml_tag :div, class: 'control-group' do
      haml_tag :label, {class: 'control-label'},"#{model.class.human_attribute_name column}"
      haml_tag :div, class: 'controls' do
        haml_tag :div, {class: 'value'}, "#{value}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the way I'm using it:

```
= detail_line(@order, 'number', @order.number)
```

The output is the following:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="controls">
     <div class="value"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: try this :-  = detail_line(@order, 'number', @order.number).html_safe

Comment: @Rubyman thanks for your response, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def detail_line(model, column, value)
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :div, class: 'control-group' do
      haml_tag :label,"#{model.class.human_attribute_name column}", {class: 'control-label'}
      haml_tag :div, class: 'controls' do
        haml_tag :div, "#{value}", {class: 'value'}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes! this did the trick! I had to switch the parameters order in the haml_tag function. Thanks!